# Where is the spec for "grand total" in oracles group by grouping sets?

Tags: sql, oracle

This is a valid sql statment for oracle 11 sql:

```
select LASTNAME, SUM(ID) from PERSON group by grouping sets ((LASTNAME), ())
```

But I can not find the specification for the grand total "()" in the [Oracle® Database SQL Language Reference](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/toc.htm). Can someone please show me where I can find the specification for this?

Answer (score 1):

You mean [this](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25554/aggreg.htm#DWHSG8631)?

Comment: Thanks. This page is not bad. :) But these are more or less examples. If you take only the SQL Reference, then there is no such function "grand total" in the formal description.

Comment: @ollins, you're right. I don't find it in the official docs. I found it in an article on [orafaq.com](http://www.orafaq.com/node/56) :) `A blank set ( ) in the GROUPING SETS clause calculates the overall aggregate`

Answer (score 0):

Why not just:

```
select lastname, sum(id)
from person
group by rollup(lastname);
```

This should give you the total you seek.

Comment: I'm writing a oracle sql parser and I want to stay in line with the Oracle SQL Language Reference.